# Newrelic - Laravel Octane

Tags: laravel, newrelic, laravel-octane

We moved Lumen to Laravel Octane and I was trying to install newrelic for php but there are no requests in our newrelic interface. Is there any way to install Laravel Octane using Roadrunner or Swoole?

Answer (score 0):

RoadRunner supports NewRelic via dedicated middleware or via OpenTelemetry: https://roadrunner.dev/docs/middleware-newrelic/2.x/en, https://roadrunner.dev/docs/middleware-otel/2.x/en

Comment: Hi Rustatian, thanks for sharing. I'm getting this error: 2023-05-08T21:03:42.000+0700 WARN http         requested middleware does not exist {"requested": "new_relic"}

Comment: Hey Radu :) Unfortinately, there is no `new_relic` middleware anymore. It was replaced (https://github.com/roadrunner-server/roadrunner/releases/tag/v2.11.0) a year ago with the OpenTelemetry plugin: https://roadrunner.dev/docs/lab-otel/2023.x/en

Comment: We had to create a middleware to manualy start (and finish) new relic transactions. As far as I know, new relic is not fully compatible with swoole.